# Serilog slow, bad performance

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

Am I doing something wrong or Serilog has awful performance?

Create a new Asp.Net Core 5.0 webapi project, add a reference to Serilog.AspNetCore nuget package and the following configuration code. Serilogs adds 15ms per request! In my maching jumps from 5ms to 20ms in a release build.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer, but would like to add that your benchmark is flawed. The value of a benchmark where the web server is running everything in memory, doesn't connect to a database and doesn't send any HTTP request is close to nil. It's not even a comparison. It's like comparing nothing to something.

Comment: Has it ever occurred to you that op is posting scenario that is small enough to fit into a stackoverflow page?  A real world scenario is too big for readers to try to reproduce themselves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The performance hit is likely not Serilog itself, but the fact that **you're writing all logs to the Console synchronously**, which blocks the request thread and will have some impact on performance.

If you were using any other logging library that ends up calling `Console.WriteLine` I'd expect you to get similar perf. results.

A common pattern is to use the [`Async` sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async), and write to the Console on a background thread. E.g.:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Async(writeTo => writeTo.Console()) // <<#<<#<<
    .CreateLogger();
```

Of course, writing directly to the Console from a web app is usually not the best approach... [There are much better Sinks you can use](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) to target directly the place(s) where you'll store your logs.

Comment: Why is writing to the console so slow?

Comment: @JasonCheng because writing to the console is supposedly a sequential blocking call even if there have been improvements in later versions of .net core

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down

Comment: Adding that single made things as fast as if logging was disabled .